# Integration with Qform in Mailster, Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using QForm in my Wordpress site ad i was searching a way to integrante with Mailster in the same site

The [Author](https://support.themecatcher.net/quform-wordpress-v2/guides/integration/mailster) of Qform has [this code](https://support.themecatcher.net/quform-wordpress-v2/guides/integration/mailster) to make it work in PHP 5.3+, but it doesn't work

```
    add_filter('quform_post_process_1', function (array $result, Quform_Form $form) {
if (function_exists('mailster_subscribe')) {
    $email = $form->getValue('quform_1_3');
    $name = $form->getValue('quform_1_4');
    $lists = array('Default List');
    $doubleOptIn = false;
    $data = array(
        'firstname' => $name[2],
        'lastname' => $name[4]
    );

    mailster_subscribe($email, $data, $lists, $doubleOptIn);
}

return $result;
```

}, 10, 2);

But when i run the code i only get the email in the List but the name only has 2 letters in it

How can i resolver this?

My server runs in PHP 7.3.17